# Adding a column name to a table column without a name

Tags: r

I have data as follows:

```
dat <- structure(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
            TRUE), dim = c(3L, 3L), dimnames = list(c("A", "B", 
                                                      "C"), c("[0,25) D", "[0,25) E", NA)))

name_vec <- "[0,25) F"
```

What I want to do is the following:

```
colnames(dat )[length(dat )] <- name_vec[i]
```

But this gives the error:

```
 Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

I am failing to understand why this does not work or what the error means.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This would work if `dat` was a data frame since a data frame is basically a list of columns, so its length is the number of its columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to do the following:

```
colnames(dat)[ncol(dat)] <- name_vec

  [0,25) D [0,25) E [0,25) F
A     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
B    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
C     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
```

Since your `dat` is a matrix, `length` would return the number of elements in the matrix, which is 9 in your case. However, you do not have 9 columns, therefore it gives you the error.

```
class(dat)
[1] "matrix" "array" 

length(dat)
[1] 9

ncol(dat)
[1] 3
```

So the correct function to use should be `ncol`.

Comment: Thanks! I have been staring at this for ages. It somehow never occurred to me to use `ncol`.